# Issue rendering default date on alert in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 `AlertController` to create an alert that lets a user add a task. The issue is, that until a user clicks on the date input, no date shows. I have tried adding both a `min` and `max` as well.

Code is as follows

```
async addCustomTask() {
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Add custom task',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'task',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'I would like to..'
    },
    {
      name: 'dueDate',
      type: 'date'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: () => {
        return false;
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: (data) => {
        this.addTask(data.task, moment.tz(data.dueDate, this.account.timezone));
      }
    }
  ]
});
await alert.present();
};
```

Looks like this when it loads up

[image: first image]

The moment you click it, it all begins to work as needed. It submits as a date as well, in the correct format.

[image: second image]

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.3 (/Users/sam/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.9
   @angular/cli                  : 6.2.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.4.0, (and 11 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v11.0.0 (/Users/sam/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: What is your ionic version ?

Comment: Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.0

Comment: just updated to 4.0.2 - same issue

Comment: This is what I am seeing [link](https://imgur.com/FEFiMjc)

Comment: looks like you have it running on your browser. this only happens when i deploy to ios or emulate ios on my machine... in browser, i get same results as you

Comment: Validating this behavior

Answer (score 0):

My Current Ionic version is 4.12.0, needed an alert-popup to take input from user StartDate and EndDate from the user for a filter. What I learned is that it allows you to add the "date" type HOWEVER, it only supports "STRING" for value & max values. Also, remember not to mix the input types.  The following is my code

```
private format_date(dt: any) {
    var today = new Date(dt);
    let dd: any = today.getDate();
    let mm: any = today.getMonth() + 1;
    const yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = `0${dd}`;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = `0${mm}`;
    }
    return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
}
async presentPopover() {
    const dt = new Date();
    this.firstDate =   dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ((dt.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1) : (dt.getMonth() + 1) ) + '-01';
    this.maxDate = this.format_date(dt);
    this.lastDay = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth() + 2, 0);
    this.lastDay = this.format_date(this.lastDay);

    if(new Date(this.lastDay) > dt) {
      this.lastDay = this.format_date(dt);
    }
    const alerts = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Filter',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'fromDt',
          type: 'date',
          value: this.firstDate,
          max: this.maxDate
        },
        {
          name: 'toDt',
          type: 'date',
          value: this.lastDay,
          max: this.maxDate
        }
      ],
      buttons: 
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {
              console.log('Confirm Ok');
              this.fetchData();
            }
          }
      ]
    });
    await alerts.present();    
}
```